# Disable wordpress image sizes generation

Tags: images, filters, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I'm trying to disable image sizes generation in wordpress.

When I use:

```
print_r( get_intermediate_image_sizes() );
```

it shows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => thumbnail
    [1] => medium
    [2] => medium_large
    [3] => large
    [4] => 1536x1536
    [5] => 2048x2048
)
```

So i tried:

```
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'filter_image_sizes');
function filter_image_sizes($sizes) {
    unset( $sizes['medium']);
    unset( $sizes['medium_large']);
    unset( $sizes['large']);
    unset( $sizes['1536x1536']);
    unset( $sizes['2048x2048']);
    return $sizes;
});
```

and

```
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes', 'filter_image_sizes');
function filter_image_sizes($sizes) {
    unset( $sizes['medium']);
    unset( $sizes['medium_large']);
    unset( $sizes['large']);
    unset( $sizes['1536x1536']);
    unset( $sizes['2048x2048']);
    return $sizes;
});
```

but it doesn't work. Setting values in admin menu doesn't work too.

```
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes', '__return_empty_array', 99 );
```

this work's, but deletes all image sizes and I want to leave thumbnails..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function filter_image_sizes() {
    foreach ( get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $size ) {
        if (in_array( $size, array('medium', 'medium_large', 'large') ) ) {
            remove_image_size( $size );
        }
    }
}

add_action('init', 'filter_image_sizes');
```

Comment: Well, it deletes my woocommerce image sizes.

Comment: Remove the "!" before in_array() Or retake my code, I have change it

Comment: It's better but it deletes '1536x1536', '2048x2048' sizes. Hmm...

Comment: Remove the '1536x1536' and '2048x2048' size from the array ;) Or retake my code haha